# jQuery JSONP "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

Here's my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: User.baseURL + 'api/users/briefProfile',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success:function(data,text,xhqr){
        //var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log("ERROR");
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

        console.log("complete");
    }

});
```

The error is: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

I get a response of 200 in Chrome (latest).  I get all of the content in the response that is valid JSON.  I don't really care that the browser isn't parsing it correctly, but I would really like to get access to it in the complete callback.

Any idea what is
a) causing the error?
b) how to get to the returned content client-side?

Comment: Please show us your ajax response

Comment: I'm actually getting a 401 error, now, but before, I was getting a JSON string returned that resembled: `{"guid":"E5FC2115FF59","lastName":"Smith","JSESSIONID":"HVQN6jITo8aa8KrHV"...}`

Comment: The problem might be that when the JSESSIONID cookie is set during login (via ajax), the JSESSIONID in the Request Cookies doesn't match.  I also can't see these cookies in the `document.cookie`. I'd like to destroy them, but am unsure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

server need support [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

and response should be like:

```
jsonpcallbackname&&jsonpcallbackname({{"guid":"E5FC2115FF59","lastName":"Smith","JSESSIONID":"HVQN6jITo8aa8KrHV"...}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Server ( web service ) has to support JSONP ( Cross browser support ).

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to add a callback function something like this in your code

```
url: User.baseURL + 'api/users/briefProfile?jsoncallback=callbackFunction',

function callbackFunction() {
     // code to execute in success handler
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar problem and can fix this with `eval`. try this:

```
 eval("(" + data + ")")
```

Comment: eval() is evil.  You also didn't mention where you would put this code, e.g. in the complete callback.